# Pagination Not Returning Any Results in DotNetCore 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've added paging to my headers in DotNetCore 3.0 and I've followed a video tutorial on Udemy to do this, but it's not returning any results in the response. Before I added paging this worked fine and did return the users, but since adding the headers the status response is 200 OK as expected, but no results.

This modifies the headers to return the page size, current page etc (this is where I suspect the problem is as the camelCaseFormatter is not applied either):

```
public static void AddPagination(this HttpResponse response, int currentPage, int itemsPerPage, int totalItems, int totalPages) {
    var paginationHeader = new PaginationHeader(currentPage, itemsPerPage, totalItems, totalPages);
    var camelCaseFormatter = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    camelCaseFormatter.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    response.Headers.Add("Pagination", JsonConvert.SerializeObject((paginationHeader, camelCaseFormatter)));
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Pagination");
}
```

This is the Users Controller which does the work of actually getting the users from the DB:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers([FromQuery]UserParams userParams) {
    var users = await _repo.GetUsers(userParams);
    var usersToReturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserForListDto>>(users);
    Response.AddPagination(users.CurrentPage, users.PageSize, users.TotalCount, users.TotalPages);
    return Ok(usersToReturn);
}
```

This is the Repo (so the GetUsers call that is above):

```
public async Task<PagedList<User>> GetUsers(UserParams userParams)
{
   var users = _context.Users.Include(p => p.Photos);
   return await PagedList<User>.CreateAsync(users, userParams.PageSize, userParams.PageSize);
}
```

The CreateAsync Method and PagedList Class:

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    public PagedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        TotalCount = count;
        PageSize = pageNumber;
        CurrentPage = pageNumber;                
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double) pageSize);
        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
          var count = await source.CountAsync();
          var items = await source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
          return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
     }
}
```

And Finally the UserParams class used to calculate the pageSize etc.

```
public class UserParams
{
    private const int MaxPageSize = 50;
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    private int pageSize = 10;
    public int PageSize
    {
        get { return pageSize; }
        set { pageSize = (value > MaxPageSize) ? MaxPageSize : value; }
    }

}
```

The result I get back from Postman is a Status 200 OK with an empty JSON object ([]).

Comment: In your repo, you are calling the `PagedList.CreateAsync` and passing `PageSize` for `pageNumber`...  Could that be it?

Comment: That got it thanks :)